# OSError: [Errno 110] ETIMEDOUT with BLE on Nucleo WB55RG

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, micropython, nucleo

I am trying to make communicate two NUCLEO-WB55RG with each other using BLE. I tried to do it following this [procedure](https://stm32python.gitlab.io/fr/docs/Micropython/BLE/BLEGAP) in micropython, but when I execute the code on the card, I get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 110] ETIMEDOUT
```

In my research I found that this problem came from the fact that my component did not activate its bluetooth module, so I increased the **ETIMEDOUT** to 20s just in case but nothing changes.

I turn therefore here to know if somebody already had this problem and if yes how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem.

To using the BLE on STM32 WB we need add BLE Stack on Firmware. (If FUS is not up to date, update it too). And for micropython we need add BLE Stack Extended on firmware.